# After installing Ubuntu, nothing happens

Tags: boot, usb

I just installed Ubuntu, and it asked for me to restart the computer, so I did it(Yes, I did put it to boot on HD). After the computer turns on, nothing happens. It's just a black screen, with "_" flickering like it's something to write with, but I can't write anything.

I tried using my usb boot again, this time I pressed F6, as I read somewhere it could make something, so I got to that screen and checked the disc, it said it was okay. So I went on to using the last option, booting the system on the HDD, and it gave me a Boot error.

E: Checked the memory, nothing is wrong with it. Just some insights, it's a laptop that I'm formatting so I can give it to my mom, it had Windows 7 and although it was pretty slow (too much things installed), it was running perfectly.

E²: Tried disconnecting and reconnecting the HDD, it didn't work.
I used the boot drive to "Try Ubuntu" and tried accessing my HD from there, it seems fine. Idk what it should look like, but the HD is working at least.

Image of what's in the HD:

[image]

Tried making the usb boot with Rufus and Unetbootin, neither worked.

E³: I tried all the solutions from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it). I've already insured that my ISO and usb flash drive isn't corrupted or anything, and I can boot with the usb and install Ubuntu normally. When I try to boot my pc from the HDD, nothing happens, just a flickering "_". I tried pressing <kbd>Right Shift</kbd> while on that screen, nothing happens. Tried pressing some other keys while on that screen, nothing happens. Only thing that works is pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>, which restarts the computer. When trying to boot from the USB using the option "Boot from first hard disk", an error pops up:

```
Booting from local disk...
Boot error
```

(I don't know if I should answer those answers in the answer section or edit my original post. Gonna edit the original post for the time being)

Yes, I don't have anything installed but Ubuntu atm. It may be a mistake uninstalling completely Windows before knowing if I would be able to reinstall it or install something else, but anyway, I did it. I tried both pressing and spamming <kbd>Right Shift</kbd> and <kbd>Esc</kbd>. Neither did anything different than the usual.

Also, if you need any information about the laptop, I can try and give it to you.

Comment: I have encountered the same problem on an very old HP desktop PC. It seems that sometimes it can't "see" its hard drive. Check the hard disk, the connecting wire, and even the motherboard (hopefully, this last one is not faulty).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Comment: If you only have Ubuntu, then you may not get grub menu. If BIOS hold shift key from start, If UEFI press Escape key (perhaps several times). Then use above link on black screen issues. If nVidia or AMD nomodeset usually works, but you need to install proprietary driver. If just Intel video you may need a different boot parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I dont really know why this is the case, but for some reason, I cant install 64 bit operating systems. I didnt know that that was a thing, but I tried installing the 32 bits one and it worked! So moral of the history; try x86 aswell.